# How to create integration tests for JMS consumer

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, activemq-artemis

I'm using ActiveMQ Artemis to send an `Object` from a microservice and receive that `Object` in the other microservice using the `@JMSListener`. I want to test the receiver. How do I mock the received `Object`? I have tried this but the test is failing due to comparison failure getting `null`.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ConsumerTests {

    @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Test
    public void foo() throws JMSException {        
        this.jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("foo", "A");
        this.jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(10_000);
        assertThat(this.jmsTemplate.receiveAndConvert("foo")).isEqualTo("A");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're getting `null` from `receiveAndConvert` that indicates a message wasn't actually received. Can you confirm that a message is actually being sent successfully (i.e. the message-count of the queue `foo` is > 0)?